# In using a VNC to control a computer, is it possible to have the cursor go to where you touch?

Tags: input-methods, vnc, accessibility

I don't have an Android device, but I'm thinking of getting a Nexus tablet, and using [android-vnc-viewer](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) to make the Nexus an input device to control the PC, and provide faster cursor movement/text editing. Both screens would be a mirror of each other.

From VNC videos that I see on YouTube, such as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTKX6QMBgck#t=0m30s), after optionally zooming in, you can touch the screen, and slide it to move the view. However, the cursor remains centered. The cursor seems to only move when you touch a button/control.

Once I'm happy with the view, can I lock it? Screen touches would then just move the cursor to where I touch. I already know of text manipulation commands once a cursor is within text such as words, sentences, or paragraphs; I'd rather not have to double tap to move the cursor and select, as I have some RSI (repetitive strain injuries)/Tendinosis.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app has multiple input modes. In the default, tapping the display moves and clicks the mouse. In another mode, the display acts like a trackpad, so dragging along the screen causes the mouse to move accordingly on the remote system. See [the "input modes" sections of the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/wiki/Documentation#Input_Modes) for details. You can change the input mode from the app menu without disconnecting.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that I want either “Touch Mouse Pan and Zoom”, or “Mouse Control Mode”.